# StarRocks Regexp module falild working with MultiChar-set

Tags: regex

StarRocks Regexp falild working with MultiChar set,example:

```
[^a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9fa5]
```

it will get Exception:

**'\u' at index 10 not supported in a character class**

good guys,do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid StarRocks cannot support this right now. You can share this in their Slack channel (you can find the link in their Github project). The community will put it in its roadmap.